# TypeError: str.charAt is not a function at parse (/app/node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:13:11)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

I have a node and express api deployed on Heroku and the api works fine for normal GET requests but when I try to Get or Post a request that involves querying a Postgre database from heroku add ons, such as registering a new user , it gives me error with this error log:

```
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984122+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: str.charAt is not a function

2020-09-13T18:48:39.984146+00:00 app[web.1]: at parse (/app/node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:13:11)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984147+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new ConnectionParameters (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js:56:42)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984148+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Client (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:19:33)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984148+00:00 app[web.1]:     at BoundPool.newClient (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:201:20)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984149+00:00 app[web.1]:     at BoundPool.connect (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:195:10)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at BoundPool.query (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:343:10)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/routes/UserAuth/jwtAuth.js:19:33
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984151+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2020-09-13T18:48:39.984151+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities due to which you might be getting this error :

1.You are trying to access some other datatype as a string.

2.You are passing this as a callback, but str.charAt() returns a character and not function.

Check for both scenarios and since you have not shared code snippet, so could not suggest the exact code implemented solution.